# Remove an item from a list in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create a list of items and delete them one by one. I have used `(click)` and `removeUser()` to delete the single item, unfortunately the output is that no matter what button is clicked, all the 3 items are deleted at the same time. Please help. Thank you

```js
export class UserlistComponent {
     users = [
      {
        id : '1',
        name: 'Jack',
        age: '33'
      },
      {
        id : '2',
        name: 'Kim',
        age: '44'
      },
      {
        id : '3',
        name: 'Mag',
        age: '22'
      },

        ]
  
    removeUser(id:string): void{ 
          this.users = this.users.filter(user => user.id !== user.id)
    }
  
}
```

```html
<li *ngFor="let user of users">

    {{user.name}} is {{user.age}} years old
    <button (click)="removeUser(user.id)">Remove</button>


</li>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using your filter on `user.id` for both sides of the comparison operator.

You need to compare with your method's parameter:

```js
removeUser(id:string): void{ 
    this.users = this.users.filter(user => user.id !== id)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Fix to your question**

You are using the filter statement incorectly. You should use the parementer in `removeUser` function to filter down the list.

```
removeUser(id:string): void{ 
    this.users = this.users.filter(user => user.id !== id)
}
```

**Better Approach**

You could just splice the unwanted elements with [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

**Template**

```
<li *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index">
    {{user.name}} is {{user.age}} years old
    <button (click)="removeUser(i)">Remove</button>
</li>
```

**Component.ts**

```
removeUser(index): void{ 
    this.users.splice(index, 1)
}
```